# Ajax Posting json to springMVC with ObjectNode

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jackson

I'am trying to develop Spring MVC application.and use JQuery on the client side to post Json to the webservice 
but i have this error : **code 415 | Unsupported Media Type**

**Jquery Part :**

```
jQuery.post(rootURL + "/json/deployWorkflow",JSON.stringify({ "command": "on" }), function(response) {
            console.log("ok........");
        })
```

**java Part :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deployWorkflow" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void deployWorkflow(@RequestBody ObjectNode jsonData){
      System.out.println(jsonData.toString());
          }
```

Comment: Try adding `dataType:"json"` in jQuery.post and change controller to `@RequestMapping(value = "/deployWorkflow" , method = RequestMethod.POST, accept="application/json")`

Comment: it's not working , i have the same error

Comment: org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode

Comment: That will not work. Try using `@RequestBody String jsonData` and manually handling the deserialization

Comment: it will cause many problem for me, Because I already prepare an ObjetNode parser, just a little RMQ: when I use jersy, it works without problem for me , but i need spring Mvc

Comment: I see your point, but I don't have any other solution to propose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution:

JQuery part:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: rootURL + "/json/deployWorkflow", 
                dataType: "json",
                data:x,
                async: false,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('ok........data' + data );
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error:  status: "+textStatus+" er:"+ errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

java part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deployWorkflow" , method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers="Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public void deployWorkflow(@RequestBody ObjectNode jsonData){
          System.out.println(jsonData.toString());
         }
```